# Are Square and equilateral triangle the only convex regular ngons that can be composed to smaller versions of themselves?

Tags: geometry, fractals, pigeonhole-principle

While I was trying to make an analogous question to [Select $n^2 + 1$ points in the unit square. Show that at least two points are no more than a distance $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ apart](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426441/select-n2-1-points-in-the-unit-square-show-that-at-least-two-points-are-no), using equilateral triangles, I ended up with : Select $2^n + 1$ points in a unit equilateral triangle. Show that at least two points are no more than a distance $\frac{1}{2^n}$ apart.

But then I got stuck! there was no other shape that the trick of decomposing a shape to smaller version of itself can be applied (short of fractals that is).

So I had to ask this question: Are Square and equilateral triangle the only convex regular ngons that can be composed to smaller versions of themselves?

Comment: no, i dont think so, but i have a hard time coming up with a counter-example at this time

Comment: see [n-flakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-flake) if that interests you

Comment: see also [self-similar regular polygons](http://www.scipress.org/e-library/rpf/pdf/chap2/0023.PDF)

Comment: @NikosM. : Thank you for the N-Flakes, yes it definitely intrests me, didnt even know it existed! Thanks again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  To decompose a regular n-gon into smaller versions of itself, the interior points have to have the surrounding angles add up to $360^\circ$. The only regular polygons that have angles that are an integer division of $360^\circ$ are the triangle, the square, and the hexagon.  The hexagon has angles of $120^\circ$, but that makes places that only two meet be concave, so you can't make the edges straight.